# CakePHP - Re-imported model and (i18n) translate with empty strings

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translation, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

The problem is that I import a model.

```
App::import('Model', 'Carrier');
$this->Carrier = new Carrier;
```

And I re-import and instacing this model later. Normally it would work as well. However, this is a multi-language site. And the second instacing it returns with an empty string.

I tried this

```
App::import('Model', 'Carrier');
$this->Carrier = new Carrier;
... blabla...
App::import('Model', 'Carrier');
$this->getCarrier = new Carrier;
... blabla...
```

and tried this:

```
App::import('Model', 'Carrier');
$this->Carrier = new Carrier;
... blabla...
unset($this->Carrier);
App::import('Model', 'Carrier');
$this->Carrier = new Carrier;
... blabla...
```

Same result: the second instacing it returns with an empty string from database.

My translate model:

```
<?php
class Carrier extends AppModel
        {
        var $name = 'Carrier';
        public $actsAs = array('Translate' => array(
                                                'name',
                                                'description'
                                                     )
                                );
        }
?>
```

- i18n database table to the variety of languages...
  (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html)

**UPDATE:**

Normally result:

```
Array ( [Carrier] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => TestCarrier [description] => Example  [status] => 1 ) )
```

Wrong result with re-imported model:

```
Array ( [Carrier] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] =>  [description] => [status] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: Dont use `App::import('Model', 'Carrier'); $this->Carrier = new Carrier;`! You should always include your models using `ClassRegistry::init('Carrier')`. Also, no App::uses() needed.

Comment: I tried: ClassRegistry::init('Carrier'); $this->Carrier = new Carrier; But the result same... :-(

Comment: It is good after all. I'm sorry. I used it wrong first.
`ClassRegistry::init('Carrier')->findById(key($carriers));`
Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use App::import(). That is only for vendor classes.
Internally, its App::uses().

But for models, this does not apply, either.
Simply use ClassRegistry::init():

```
$Carrier = ClassRegistry::init('Carrier');
$results = Carrier->find(...);
```

For models cake has its own loading mechanism.